# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)+\sqrt{5}}$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Whether series : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)+\sqrt{5}}$diverges?

I've tried use Cauchy Condensation Test but i got: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln(2)+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2^n}}$$
so i used CCT one more time and got: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(2)+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2^{2^n}2^n}}$$ which diverges.
Is this correct?

Comment: Cauchy condensation applies to decreasing sequences, so you should have an argument of sort to justfiy why you can apply it to $\frac1{2^{-n}\sqrt5+n\ln2}$, but other than that it's correct.

Comment: For $n>3,$ $log(n^n)>\sqrt{5}$ so $2\log(n^n)> \log(n^n)+\sqrt 5$ and thus it is enough to show $\sum\frac{1}{\log(n^n)}$ diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{n\ln(n)+\sqrt{5}}}{\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}}=1$ .

So it suffices to test for $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ . (Due to Limit comparison test)

Apply Cauchy Condensation test:-

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{2^{n}n\ln(2)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(2)}$$ which diverges.

Answer (score 2):

The hint given in the comments by TheSilverDoe

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)+\sqrt{5}}\sim \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)}$$

is the key point to study the series.

As an alternative, following your way, after the first application of CCT we can conclude in this way:

$$\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\ln(2)+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2^n}} \ge \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\ln(2)+n\ln(2)}=\frac{1}{2\ln(2)}\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n}$$